# I'd like to know if I can use the word 'cost' like this

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to know if I can say these without changing meaning

> 1. It costs me much money to use the pool
> 2. Using the pool costs me much money.
> 3. The pool costs me much money to use.

I think #1. is the most common one, but I've seen #2.3 also being used. Can I say all of them?

Comment: The use of "much" in this context sounds a bit awkward.  I'd replace it with "a lot of", although it's not imperative.

Comment: They are very close in meaning, and which you would choose depends on what aspect of the statement you wish to emphasize— the cost, the use, or the pool respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use all of them without changing the meaning, but it would be better to use 'a lot' instead of 'much'.

Answer (score 1):

All of the sentences are valid, and all three of them could be said (they mean pretty much the same thing). However, if you want to make yourself clearer and sound more natural to a native English speaker, you should replace your "much" with either "a lot of" (It costs me a lot of money to use the pool), or, if you'd like to say that it's too expensive to use the pool, use "too much" (It costs me too much money to use the pool). Which one you choose depends on what you're trying to convey.